# How can I create a cylinder linking two points with Python withour using blender's bpy?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, 3d, pyopengl

I want to position a cylinder such that the center of one end is at (x0, y0, z0) and the center of the other end is at (x1, y1, z1) using the pure Python API.

I want to attain this using Python OpenGL or any other GL libs but not blender lib

**My Problem** 
I searched in stackoverflow and found this question

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5898/how-can-i-create-a-cylinder-linking-two-points-with-python

```
But it is using blender and I don't want it
```

I need to run the python script from command line or pycharm ide

So bpy module can't work outside blender

I want a function like this format

```
cylinder_between(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, rad):
```

The function have to display a cylinder

Please guide me

> 2) also suggest how to clear the screen fully after drawing the
>   cylinder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use *modern* OpenGL then you've to generate a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) and to write a [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader).

A solution with less lines of code is to use [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) and either [`gluCylinder`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluCylinder.xml) or [`glutSolidCylinder`](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__geometry.html#ga6).

With this (deprecated) tool set a cylinder with few lines of code can be drawn e.g.:

```py
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
import math

def cross(a, b):
    return [a[1]*b[2]-a[2]*b[1], a[2]*b[0]-a[0]*b[2], a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0]]

def cylinder_between(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, rad):
    v = [x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1]
    height = math.sqrt(v[0]*v[0] + v[1]*v[1] + v[2]*v[2])
    axis = (1, 0, 0) if math.hypot(v[0], v[1]) < 0.001 else cross(v, (0, 0, 1))
    angle = -math.atan2(math.hypot(v[0], v[1]), v[2])*180/math.pi
    
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslate(x1, y1, z1)
    glRotate(angle, *axis)
    glutSolidCylinder(rad, height, 32, 16)
    glPopMatrix()

def draw():

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45, wnd_w/wnd_h, 0.1, 10)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluLookAt(0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)  
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    # glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE) # causes wire frame
    glColor(1, 1, 0.5)
    cylinder_between(0.2, 0.4, -0.5, -0.2, -0.4, 0.5, 0.3)

    glutSwapBuffers()
    glutPostRedisplay()

wnd_w, wnd_h = 300, 300
glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
glutInitWindowSize(wnd_w, wnd_h)
glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50)
glutCreateWindow("cylinder")
glutDisplayFunc(draw)
glutMainLoop()
```

[image]

See also [Immediate mode and legacy OpenGL](https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/blob/master/readme/content_python_legacy.md)

---

> Is there any way to implement manually do pan , rotate , tilt ,move the viewport like we do in 3D modeling software using mouse (that alt+mmb )

See:

- [How to implement camera pan like in 3dsMax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758319/how-to-implement-camera-pan-like-in-3dsmax)
- [Proper way to handle camera rotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54027740/proper-way-to-handle-camera-rotations)
- [How to implement zoom towards mouse like in 3dsMax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057549/how-to-implement-zoom-towards-mouse-like-in-3dsmax)

Comment: @LordCommander I'm surprised, because I've developed it (and tested) with python 3.7 on Win10 x64. PyOpenGL I've installed form [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl)